# Singular vs plural forms for entities in CMS website

Tags: url, links, clean-urls, ux

Let's say I have a (frontend) website where users can register and post, just like StackExchange, which makes use of a REST API to fetch the data. So the website is located at `https://www.example.com` and the REST API is located at `https://api.example.com`.

In the REST API, I (and probably most REST API developers (see many guides about REST API naming conventions online)) prefer to use plural forms for resources (e.g. `https://api.example.com/users`, `https://api.example.com/users/john`).

But what about the frontend (the website that the users and search engines will face)? I see most websites prefer to use singular forms, at least for `users`, like `https://www.example.com/user/john` instead of `https://www.example.com/users/john`.

Are there any good reasons for this in terms of UX (and maybe SEO)?

I think using the same plural form format for the user-facing website makes it easier for use as a developer (for uniformity reasons), but on the other hand, URLs like `https://www.example.com/user/john` seem more common to me and more user-friendly than `https://www.example.com/users/john`.

All discussions I could find on this topic are only considering REST API naming specifically or only focusing on websites such as blogs and e-commerce websites with multiple categories.